# Check whether a mysql_connect() failed or not?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey i'm trying to find out whether my sql query failed or not. I want it so if it does fail redirect to form page using the code below:

```
$checkconnection = mysql_connect('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass)
                                                or die();


if(!$checkconnection)
{
$_SESSION['errormsg'] = "<div style='padding-left: 50px;color:#FF0000'>Cannot connect to specfied database!</div>";
header("Location: install.php");
}else{
echo('Connection Successful!');
}
```

using that all it says is this:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'nzcraftn_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/nzcraftn/public_html/phishnet/install/install_submit.php on line 17
```

Comment: Which means wither you have no privileges on the database you are trying to access, or you typed the wrong password.

Comment: your password or username is wrong

Comment: It's weird that the `or die` doesn't trigger......... Also, on a side note, don't put markup in your error message.....

Comment: @Rudie, the `or die()` does indeed trigger - it's just that 1) his warning messages are set to be displayed and 2) his `die()` isn't outputting anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
$checkconnection = @mysql_connect('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass)
```

it will hide default error and trigger your own

Comment: It won't help him with the session though, as it might be redirecting before it manages to save the `error-msg`.

Comment: @ninetwozero: yes it will. Sesssion is saved before redirecting

Comment: In most cases: yes, but sometimes it won't actually save the data (leaving you with broken functionality)... hence the existence of [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php). Most cases don't need it though. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `mysql_connect` being false only indicates failure.  If it returns `FALSE`, the `or die()` expression will exit the php script.  That's the reason why you don't sea any of it's output.

Remove the `or die()` command, and display the actual error in your `if( !$checkconnection )` clause.  The reported error can be retrieved using `mysql_error()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's only displaying the warning because your `or die()` isn't outputting anything (empty parameter list). Try this instead:

```
<?php
    //Start the session
    session_start(); 

    //Do the conntection
    $checkconnection = @mysql_connect('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass);

    //Check if it's valid
    if(!$checkconnection) {

        //Add it up to the session, and redirect
        $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "<div style='padding-left: 50px;color:#FF0000'>Cannot connect to specfied database!</div>";
        session_write_close();
        header("Location: install.php");
        exit();

    } else{

        //Yay
        echo('Connection Successful!');

    }
?>
```

Comment: Would the downvoter mind telling me why I got it? Constructive criticism is great you know. Edit: Thanks @hakre, forgot about that one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by genesis just supresses the warning, but still might work

If you want it 'clean' you can try/catch the error:

(directly from the comments on php.net/mysql_connect:

```
// Assign variables
        global $db_connection, $db_server, $db_database, $db_username, $db_password;
        $db_server = $server;
        $db_database = $database;
        $db_username = $username;
        $db_password = $password;

        // Attempt connection
        try
        {
            // Create connection to MYSQL database
            // Fourth true parameter will allow for multiple connections to be made
            $db_connection = mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password, true);
            mysql_select_db ($database);
            if (!$db_connection)
            {
                throw new Exception('MySQL Connection Database Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
                $CONNECTED = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: adding `try/catch` doesn't add anything useful.  Instead, it hides the mysql error-handling idiom inside yet another API.  Wrapping never simplifies, nor cleans anything.  (of course, that's just my opinion)